# Idea Needed for Positioning an objects in a Video - OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-capture

I am looking for some simple implementation ideas in order to develop an application.

I have Thresholded certain colour from an video -->[Thresholded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFXDv.png)

What I need is the Following :

1. Now, I would like to create a template for a new co-ordinate system with in the thresholded region. Then I would introduce an object(shown blue colour) within those region as shown here--> [Object Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n81ll.png)
2. The Idea is to get the location co-ordiate of the object dynamically from the video based on my co-ordinate system which I mentioned above.

It would be really nice if you can tell me how to achieve it. Especially I need to know :

1. How do I create such template ?
2. How can I manually position the co-ordinates ?
3. How to dynamically track the location ?

   Currently I am using OpenCV and C++.

Comment: Are you asking for algorithm or do the job for you?

Comment: I need Algorithm to implement this work.

Comment: It's not place for this try on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: break your problem down into subproblems. start with the first thing you cannot solve alone and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a LUT (look up table) with coordinates that range from 0 to 4 within that quadrilateral. This is called perspective mapping, and I recently finished a similar implementation that allows me to know the position of an object within my coordinate system.

[This](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2010_fall/Papers/proj.pdf) is the resource that I used to learn about perspective mapping and translate it into code. Good luck.